# Loop over mulitdimensional array (for plotting filled.contour Plots)

Tags: r, for-loop, multidimensional-array, plot, contour

My aim is to get one contour plot per timestep (for soil moisture data of a 5m x 5m field). I still work with random values but need it later in my thesis for concrete messurements.

First, I created a 3-dimensional array called `BF_array` with 10 5 x 5 matrices.
If I access a specific matrix of the array in my filled.contour command, it works (see image below). For the image, I used `BF_array[,,9]` as `z`.
But as soon as I try to iterate over the different matrices of my array it says that there's no proper `z` matrix specified in `contour()`.

Can you tell me what's wrong with my code?
Thanks for your help :)

The array used

[image: The used array]

Contour Plot with one matrix of my array

[image: Contour Plot with one matrix of my array]

```
for (i in 1:dim(BF_array)[3]){
x <- 1:5 
y <- 1:5 
z <-i
cls <-rainbow(70,start=0.001,end=1.) 
filled.contour(abs(x),abs(y),z,ylim = c(1,5),col = cls, nlevels=50, main="Wassergehalte in %nFK", plot.axes={axis(1);axis(2);contour(abs(x),abs(y),z,nlevels=20,add=T,lwd=1,col="brown",axes=F)})}
```

Comment: You are passing an integer to `filled.contour` and not a subset of your data. Not sure if that's intended. Is it?

Comment: No, I just tryed the expression " for (i in 1:dim(BF_array)[3]) " after my first choice with "for (i in BF_array[,,10]) " didn't work, either. It had given me the same warning message...